# What are some tips for cheap and solid hw raid controller card for running ESXi?

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, hardware-raid, hardware

ESXi is great product, however little bit picky about hardware. Can you please reccommend me some hardware raid controllers which work 100% out of the box and are also price-efficient ?

I know about this page http://www.vm-help.com/esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php - however most of the hardware in the list is pretty expensive. So I would be glad for tips on cheap and proven raid controller cards.

Not to forget - I am looking for running RAID 1.

Comment: This is a shopping question and does not belong on serverfault, please refer to the faq :)

Comment: @LucasKauffman: You might be right, however, there is no place, where you could get such qualite information and it is also very hardware and server related.

Comment: @Frodik Yes it's certainly hardware related, but that doesn't overrule our FAQ, which explicitly states that product recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [hp smart array e200](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/arraycontrollers/smartarraye200/index.html), in cheap scenarios.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I was looking for something costing half price or less than e200. Probably "cheap" is too relative term ;-) Maybe I should have said "cheapest" cards ...

Comment: Didn't find anything cheaper than that with the same functionality, frankly.

Comment: cheap and solid do not go together

Comment: Yeah, choose only 2 from the following: fast, good, cheap :)